# Large data table overflows fixed width container - can I make the container expand?

Tags: css

I am working on a web page that used a fixed width layout, centered in the browser. The width of the centered container is set in pixels.

On a couple of pages, there is a large data table inside the content container. In Firefox the table overflows the fixed width container. IE is more complex and will expand the container around the table, and because of some layout issues the container uses overflow:scroll just for IE.

I need to find out if I can use a fixed width on the container, but also allow it to expand to wrap the large data table. I also need to avoid a solution where I would be modifying the HTML... I can't for example use an ID to only target those containers on pages with large tables. I need a pure CSS solution.

My feeling is that this is impossible, and I am going to HAVE to put an ID on those specific containers that need to be larger than the standard. I'm asking here because I really need a second opinion.

Just a note: I have also experimented with min/max-width, without success.

Comment: I think what you're asking is whether you can have a container with a "min-width" instead of a fixed width, right?

Comment: The problem with a min-width solution is that the container then expands to fill the browser window, when it really needs to be centered in the middle. Setting max-width in addition allows scaling and centering.

However, on most of the pages in the site I need the width to be fixed, scaling to browser window size simply breaks the layout of most pages.

I need the container to be fixed width, but also wrap around content that's too wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [min-width](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/min-width/) and [overflow](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/overflow/) don't work, you're going to need [css hacks](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+min-width+IE).

If the problem with min-width is that the container is a block-level element and expands to page width, try using a variant of [display:inline](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/display/) on that container, so it doesn't stretch. (Or maybe margin.)

Comment: Good ideas, I did try display:inline\inline-block as you suggested. This shrink-wraps the content, but then ignores the concept of max-width... the container will not expand to fit wide tables. The problem with setting margins is that they will also not allow the container to expand as needed - or they make every page fluid and flexible rather than fixed.

Comment: You didn't want max-width with inline/inline-block, you wanted min-width - so it'd always be at least XYZ units wide, but expandable. But now that I think about it, I believe IE doesn't respect max-width.